# For a public key cryptography, from where this prime numbers are generated

Tags: encryption, cryptography, primes, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

For a **public key cryptography**, from where this **prime numbers** are **generated**, is there any **predefined list** from where we pick numbers or what, in **RSA, DSA, Diffie-Hellman key agreement** etc.? I searched a lot on internet. Hope this will help me out in easy way.

Comment: You might have more success if you asked this question at the stackexchange for security: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Questions about cryptography that do not include an implementation problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may wish to consider posting this at http://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined list. Candidates are generated randomly and tested for primeness.

Answer (score 0):

[NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/) has a number of publications describing how to do this to meet their standards. For example, there is [FIPS PUB 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf), and Special Pubs [800-56A](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar2.pdf) and [56B](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56B/sp800-56B.pdf).